# Lost all files after installing Yosemite

Tags: install, macos

I upgraded to OS X Yosemite and I have lost all my files or I don't know where they are or how to get them.

I didn't realise that upgrading would delete all my files. Is there a way to go back to retrieve these files? All my business files, pics and personal files are gone.

Comment: did you find them by now ?

Comment: the same happened to me and no i didnt create another user profile. has anyone figured out how to fix this?

Comment: How did you install the new OS?  via the App Store?  a USB stick?  some other method?

Answer (score 1):

The Installation of new operating system will normally not touch your files.

What it might have happened is you created a new user account and all your files are in the old user account.

If you have admin privileges you should be able to see the old user account in sys pref users and switch to it.